# Use tab for indentation in PHP-CS-Fixer

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

How can I configure PHP-CS-Fixer to use tab for indentation?

I can see the `indentation_type` fixer

```
* indentation_type [@PSR2, @Symfony]
  | Code MUST use configured indentation type.
```

But how do I configure the indentation type? If I try to set `'indentation_type' => 'tab',`, I am getting the error

```
[indentation_type] Is not configurable.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It was there in the documentation, and some how I missed it (probably because I was searching for the term 'tab' instead of 'indentation')

For anyone else looking for the same, there is a `setIndent` method in `PhpCsFixer\Config`.

```
return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'indentation_type' => true,
    ])
    ->setIndent("\t")
    ->setLineEnding("\n")
    ->setFinder($finder)
```

Comment: It's really annoying to have these arrays and no good docs on all the rules... A method like ->useTabsForIndent() would be so much more descriptive and easy to discover with any idea providing autocomplete.

Comment: Even though having a single method would be nice, I consider it only as a minor inconvenience. Since this is a one time configuration for a project, and almost always the same across projects, I don't see the IDE autocomplete as a huge advantage.

Answer (score 2):

First create `.php_cs` file in your project root directory. Then add the below lines to `.php_cs` file

```
<?php
return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
->setRules([
    '@PSR2' => true,
    'indentation_type' => true,
])
->setIndent("\t")
->setLineEnding("\n")
->setFinder($finder)
```

Then run the below command to fix the issue

```
vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix . --config .php_cs
```

Comment: The question asks about using `tab` for indentation, and your answer explains how to use `space`.

Comment: @JoyceBabu Thank you for your comment, I have updated the code for tab.

Comment: Now this is a duplicate of the existing answer. What is the value addition?

Comment: if we have to fix the issue we need the code as well the command to fix the issue.

Comment: Configuration file `.php_cs` is outdated, rename to `.php-cs-fixer.php`.

Answer (score 1):

**2023**

> `Config::create()` has been deprecated in version 2.17 and removed in 3.0 (see upgrade guide). You should use the constructor instead.
> ([julienfalque](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/5696#issuecomment-833458761))

Now its `.php-cs-fixer.php`:

```php
<?php
use PhpCsFixer\Config;
use PhpCsFixer\Finder;

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    /*
    ->exclude('somedir') 
    maybe we should parse `./.vscode/settings.json`
    looking for "files.exclude" / "search.exclude" here?
    */
    ->in(__DIR__);

$config = new PhpCsFixer\Config();

$config->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'indentation_type' => true,
    ])
    ->setIndent("\t")
    ->setLineEnding("\n")
    ->setFinder($finder);

return $config;
```

see [documentation](https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/319d15d9150502e9c37d3edbac2d248efd8e101e/doc/config.rst).